# Best Approach for View Caching using a Proximity Filter

Tags: 7, views

I have a view that is time-based cached.

One of the options on the exposed form is a 'near me now', which sorts the results by distance and displays mileage.

The users location is provided by the IPM&V Module, and works fine with the view cache turned off.

The problem is that with cache-view turned on, sorting by near me now continues to display the results based on previous requests.  The view is 'cached' and not using the current users location.

I could simply turn views caching off, but hate losing the extra speed.

Is there a way (a hook or function) that tells views to 'refresh/clear cache' if certain conditions are met? Ie, if user selects 'near me now' do not cache.

I looked at a combination of rules/cache action, but couldn't get it to work on a specific filter input.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: How about this...
https://www.drupal.org/node/322104
...
An alternative solution would be to empty the page cache for that particular page once a day/hour to make sure that it's relatively up to date...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that really doesn't work. Since User A comes and says show me nearby items,  and then a few seconds later User B comes and shows me nearby items.   So empty the cache once a day, etc isn't a solution -- since each user has their own view results.

Answer (score 0):

How about this module:
https://www.drupal.org/files/images/Views_content_cache.png

Without testing it I cannot tell if it will expose the 'nearby' state as a filter for for the update cache  function but looks like a good place to start:
[image]

Comment: Awesome module, will come in handy for other cases.  But only seems to be on editing/adding/deleting content.  So can't use in this instance.